# Определение стилистической принадлежности текста

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи

Определите стилистическую принадлежность текста.
Укажите характерные для данного стиля лексические, морфологические, синтаксические, фразеологические, языковые признаки.
Сформулируйте цель текста.

*Что такое система здравоохранения? Система здравоохранения — это совокупность всех организаций, институтов и ресурсов, главной целью которых является улучшение здоровья. Для функционирования системы здравоохранения необходимы кадровые ресурсы, финансовые средства, информация, оборудование и материалы, транспорт, коммуникации, а также всеобщее управление и руководство. В рамках системы здравоохранения должны оказываться услуги, чутко реагирующие на потребности и справедливые с финансовой точки зрения, при уважительном отношении к людям.*

*Хорошая система здравоохранения каждый день ощутимо улучшает жизнь людей. Так, система здравоохранения приносит пользу матери, направив ей письмо с напоминанием о том, что ее сыну необходимо сделать прививку от угрожающей его жизни болезни. То же можно сказать и о семье из деревни, наконец-то получившей доступ к чистой воде из колодца, за которым ведется надлежащий уход благодаря финансированию правительством проекта в области санитарии; или о человеке с ВИЧ/СПИДом, получающем антиретровирусные препараты и советы по питанию и проходящем регулярные осмотры в доступной по стоимости клинике.*

*Окончательная ответственность за общее функционирование системы здравоохранения в стране лежит на правительстве, но разумное руководство в районах, муниципальных округах и отдельных медицинских учреждениях также очень важно.*

*Усиление систем здравоохранения и их функционирование на более справедливой основе признаны основными стратегиями борьбы с нищетой и содействия развитию.*

*Проблемы, связанные с системами здравоохранения, не ограничиваются бедными странами. В некоторых богатых странах имеются большие группы населения, не имеющие доступа к медицинской помощи из-за несправедливой организации социальной защиты, а в других странах ведется борьба против роста цен из-за неэффективного использования ресурсов.*

Comment: Предложите Ваш вариант, а мы поправим, если будет нужно. За Вас делать задание не будем.

Comment: Люди вообще учат что-нибудь?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з